# Unable to Preview other contributors as Admin

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I run a multi-author site and am Admin. I also have a user-created role for our editor called, not surprisingly, Editor and then there's another admin. The rest are all just Contributors.

A couple months ago I noticed an issue where, if I loaded ANY other users posts into the editor and tried to Preview them, I'd get an error telling me I have no permission to do it.

Now the other admin and editor are having the same issue. The only way around it is to save the changes and then publish to view.

This sounds like some DB/permissions issue, but I'll be darned if I have ANY clue where to go looking for the solution. Google searches so others with the issue from years back, but without solutions.

I have noticed that I CAN preview much older posts on the site, but not more recent posts so clearly something has happened at some point to impact newer posts.

ANY help would be great appreciated.